# Asking Python for first hour per day per month in a generated list of times

Tags: python, datetime, min

I made a function that lists information about days in a range using timedelta.

```
def gendates(days_back, days_total):
    startDt = datetime.today() + relativedelta(days=+(-1 * days_back))
    for dateOff in range(days_total *24 +1):
        dimDate = startDt + relativedelta(hours =+dateOff )
        dateYear = dimDate.year
        fiscalPer = str (dimDate.year) + 'm' + str(dimDate.month)
        calendQuar = 'Q'+ str((dimDate.month - 1)//3 +1)
        print (dimDate, dateYear, fiscalPer, calendQuar)
```

which produces

```
2019-03-24 18:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-24 19:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-24 20:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-24 21:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-24 22:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-24 23:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-25 00:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-25 01:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-25 02:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
2019-03-25 03:49:24.534863 2019 2019m3 Q1
```

Now I am being asked to log the first hour of every first day of the month. I've tried fiddling around with :

```
for x in range dimDate:
    y = min(datetime)
    print (y)
```

I've tried many variations of that, each throwing different errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Your code doesn't use the loop's index variable, and tries to take the minimum of a module, so it isn't clear what it is attempting to accomplish.

Comment: for x in range (dimDate):
            x = min(datetime)
            print (x)
right. i can fix it so that it uses the index variable, but I'm not sure what to do about the index of a module that you mention. how can I take the minimums of the monthly outputs of dimDate? this course is supposed to be beginner friendly!

Comment: Group the dates by month, and take the min of each month's dates.

Comment: used this:
        if dimDate.day == 1 and dimDate.hour == 0: 
            print (dimDate)
which got it working basically. Just have to change the print to a logging function and i'm gucci.